# ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and use of static finals: fields become null after first test

Tags: android, unit-testing, static, android-activity, junit

This is really looks like some magic is going on and I'm interested to understand why that happens :)

Here's the unit-test I have:

```
public class SelectThemeActivityTest 
    extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SelectThemeActivity> {

    private final static int[] STATIC_ARRAY = { 0, 1, 2 };

    public SelectThemeActivityTest() {
        super("com.the7art.simplewallpaper", SelectThemeActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        // some array usage here - will throw NullPointerEcxeption on second test
        // see description below
        STATIC_ARRAY[0] = 2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testFirst() {

    }
    public void testSecond() {

    }
    public void testThird() {

    }
}
```

If I run this test case the **first test completes successfully** and all the rest fail by throwing *NullPointerException* from *setUp()* - the line which tries to access STATIC_ARRAY.

What puzzles me even more is the fact that if I change the test case to extend *AndroidTestCase* instead of *ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2*, then **all tests complete successfully**! Magic! :-)

Also if I remove 'static' keyword from STATIC_ARRAY, tests succeed too.

So it's clear that something is modifying my STATIC_ARRAY by making it null between a test runs, most probably in *tearDown()* and that *something* has to do with *ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2*, but how to track that *something*? :-) Any ideas?

Comment: Your actual code might look very different, but from your sample, you should just create your array in `setUp()`.

Comment: Nope, I posted the EXACT test like I have it in Eclipse :) Yes, I guess I could create it in setUp(), or as I said fix it by removing 'static' keyword, but I'm just curious to find out what does cause this strange behavior :)

Comment: @dpimka, faced the same issue with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 junits on android (2.2 emulator) - the static fields are cleared, did you find the reason? )
seems like there is some magic android specific code in super.tearDown()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is scrubClass() method called from super.tearDown(): [google-groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f33785a59de79440). A solution is - [overriding this method](http://www.yetanothercoder.ru/2012/02/how-to-save-static-fields-in-android.html).

Answer (score 1):

Put a watch point on STATIC_ARRAY and see who modifies it, although there are not too many candidates (since the field is private, there is pretty much only one candidate, the class you just posted, so something is missing from the picture.

Comment: My code is *exactly* like the one I posted. Will try with a watchpoint, never used them until now, hope it's possible with android testcases ;)